# How do I separate merged html tags in vim?

Tags: html, vim, sparkup

How do I get this:

```
<body>
    <div>[cursor here]</div>
</body>
```

To this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        [cursor here]
    </div>
</body>
```

In a single command? I have the sparkup plugin installed but didn't come across any actions that do this

Comment: would you like to map some key for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about:

```
inoremap <c-k> <cr><esc>O
```

and ofc change `<c-k>` to whatever you like..

Comment: That seems to create a new line, but doesn't indent the cursor or the closing </div>

Comment: don't you have `filetype indent on` or something similar in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: I did not. After adding that the mapping you suggested works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    :%s/\(>\_\s\+<div>\)\([^<]*\)\(.*\)/\1\r\t\t\2\r\t\3/g

    : .................. command line
    % .................. whole file
    / .................. start search pattern
    \( ................. start group -- see \) closing at the end
    > .................. one close tag
    \_ ................. multiline search
    \s ................. one space
    \+ ................. or more
    <div> .............. one div
    \) ................. closing group one
    \( ................. open the second group
    [^<]* .............. denied list in wich no has open tag <  (everything less <)
    \) ................. closing the second group
    \( ................. opening the third group (everything else) in the next line
    .* ................. the rest of line, including the close </div>
    / .................. start of substitution pattern
    \1 ................. back reference to the group one (place them here)
    \r ................. carriage return (or simply <enter>)
    \t\t ............... 2 tabs
    \2 ................. place second group here
    \r ................. another <enter>
    \t ................. one more tab
    \3 ................. palce third group here
    / .................. end of substituition
    g .................. global command
```